# Play one of a set of audio clips randomly?

Tags: html, audio

So I'm trying to setup a web-page where when you open it, it will play a random piece of music, and when that one finishes, it will play another directly after so you get a constant stream of music, but not in the same order every time. If this goes outside the bounds of HTML and I'm looking at for instance JavaScipt than that's fine.

I know this is probably a rather easy solution, but I'm new to HTML and trying to understand it better.

Thanks in advance if I don't get back to you soon!

Answer (score 0):

This is best solved using JavaScript, which is used to add behavior to a website. HTML is primarily used to structure your site.

We can get a collection of all audio elements with the `querySelectorAll` function. Then we find a random element with the next line and call the `play` method.

```
var audio = document.querySelectorAll("audio");

function playRandom() {
    audio[Math.floor(Math.random() * audio.length)].play()
}();
```

For the second part of your question, you would want to listen for the `ended` event. Inside the event listener function, you would then call the `playRandom()` function.

```
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    playRandom();
});
```

Comment: Hm.. for some reason this doesn't seem to be working. I've put the code you sent inside of the <script></script> tags, and inside the folder with the index.html file I've put all the songs. They're all .mp3 file format if that might impact it as well. Again, sorry if this is an obvious answer, I'm not very good at all this, especially Java Script implementation in HTML